# Having trouble running a powershell script on logon as administrator

Tags: windows, powershell

I've written a script that is supposed to run at logon to change the IP of a computer (it's for staging a point of sale terminal). I had this script working previously. Now, after making some changes to it, it will not run. After restarting the terminal, nothing happens. If I check task manager, I can see that Powershell.exe is running, and is just hanging. 
The log file that I am creating has these two lines:

```
Transcript started, output file is c:\ta_staging\termlogon.log
2019-06-27 22:16:39.121     [INFO]  Checking for marker file
2019-06-27 22:16:39.215     [INFO]  No marker file found. Starting first run.
```

The script is supposed to run and check for a marker file. If the file is not found, it is supposed to get the site number from the user by popping the onscreen keyboard. After that, it will changed the IP based on the site number. 
The scheduled task is calling the script by: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -file C:\staging\termlogon.ps1 -verb runas`

The code that is getting stuck is:

```bsh
if ( $(try { !(Test-Path -Path "$scriptPath\$marker" -PathType Leaf) } catch { $false } ) )
    {
        LogInfo "No marker file found. Starting first run."
        # Get the site number that is being staged.
        # Open the On Screen Keyboard for the tech to enter the information
        Start-Process osk
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Please enter the site number.")
        LogInfo "Getting site ID from staging tech."
        $siteid = Read-Host "What is the site number being staged? Note: quick service sites must include '8' in the site number."
        LogInfo "Site ID is $siteid"
    } else {
    # Do Stuff
    }
```

I have no idea why this has stopped working or how to get it working again. Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: did your previous version NOT have the user input? many tasks run in non-interactive mode ... and that will leave your code in limbo if it tries to _interact_.

Comment: Actually no, it previously was asking for the input. And the keyboard was showing up. I added the logic checking for the marker file. That's it.

Comment: It looks like a very strange construct. What are you trying to do in the beginning?? If Try Not Test-Path...? You then close that statement and have another block starting out of nowhere. I would reconsider the whole thing. You should think....if not test-path, do something. Else do something else. You shouldn’t need to Try anything there. Test-Path is a boolean true or false. Base your action off of that result.

Comment: @m0lochwalker - The only reason for the `if ( $(try { !(Test-Path -Path "$scriptPath\$marker" -PathType Leaf) } catch { $false } ) )` construct is due to this line from ss64.com: `"Test-Path will either return $true or $false.

Test-Path will correctly test for the presence or absence of a valid path string, but if you ask it to test a path which is $null or a Zero Length String it will return an error. You capture such null/empty variables with a Try statement like this:
$TestPath = $null

if ( $(Try { Test-Path $TestPath.trim() } Catch { $false }) ) {`

Comment: @BoogaRoo - The `LogInfo` function is not new. I've been using it for a while. It is a simple function that writes to a log file.

Comment: @Harlan Ok. Are you passing $null or “” to Test-Path? I mean, it’s whatever works!

Comment: I wasn't. I removed the `Test-Path` portion, and it still works, so whatever. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution had nothing to do with the Powershell script, but the way I had the scheduled task set up. I had "Run whether user is logged on or not" selected. Once I changed it to "Run only when user is logged on" everything started working.